# What is the probability ??

Tags: probability

The probability of $\space C=1 \space$ for different values of $\space A\space$ and $\space B\space$ are given. Also $\space P(A=1)=0.65$ and $\space P(B=1)=0.77$

$P(C=1 \mid A=0 \text{ and } B=0)=0.1\\
P(C=1 \mid A=0 \text{ and } B=1)=0.99\\
P(C=1 \mid A=1 \text{ and } B=0)=0.8 \\
P(C=1 \mid A=1 \text{ and } B=1)=0.25 $

Now, we ask the same question about the modified $XOR$ Gate.
What is the probability that $\space A \space$  was $1$ if $\space C \space$ was $0$? In other words, find $\space P(A=1 \mid C=0)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please typeset your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It will make people more likely to give an answer. Also for questions like this, please provide details on where/why you are stuck.

Comment: I guess $A$ and $B$ are independent? I suggest using Bayes' theorem to invert the condition.

Comment: Is it given that each of $A, B$ and $C$ can only be $0$ and $1$? Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A = 1|C=0) = \frac{P(C=0|A=1) * P(A = 1)}{P(C=0)}$.

$P(A=1) = .65$

$P(C= 0|A=1) =  1 - P(C=1|A=1) = 1 - P(C=1|A=1,B=1) * P(B=1) - P(C=1|A=1,B=0) * P(B=0) = 1 - .25*.77 - .8*.23 = .6235$

$P(C= 0|A=0) =  1 - P(C=1|A=0) = 1 - P(C=1|A=0,B=1) * P(B=1) - P(C=1|A=0,B=0) * P(B=0) = 1 - .99*.77 - .1*.23 = .2147 $

$P(C= 0) = P(C= 0|A=0) * P(A = 0) + P(C= 0|A=1) *P(A=1) = .2147 * .35 + .6235 * .65 = .48042$

Thus, $P(A = 1|C=0) = \frac{ .6235* .65}{.48042} = .8435$.